# How to hold all derived class objects in one container?

Tags: c++

I have base class `Product` and derived classes `Book`, `Magazine` and `MusicCD`. I want to keep pointers to these objects in one array in main, container etc.

```
int main()
{
    Product* pro[100];
    pro[0] = new Book();
    pro[1] = new Magazine();
    pro[2] = new MusicCD();
}
```

The size of `pro` is 100 but I don't want a static size. products is given default and only used by user. If I want to add more objects do I have to do it manually `pro[68], pro[69]`...?

Comment: `vector<unique_ptr<Product>>`!

Answer (score 3):

The standard C++ library provides both expandable containers and safer ways of handling the pointers I suggest you use both. A `std::vector` will resize as you need it and constructed as I show below will clean up both itself and the pointers inside when main exits.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Product> > products;
    //C++11
    products.emplace_back(new Book());
    products.emplace_back(new Magazine());

    //C++03TR1 (VS 2010 and older GCC)
    // we don't have emplace_back here so we need to 
    // construct both the shared_ptr and the book if the book
    // constructor takes arguments
    // otherwise we can use the slightly more exception safe std::make_shared
    products.push_back(std::make_shared<Book>());
}
```

Comment: @user3183539 update your post with the code that's not working

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has a host of variable-size generic containers that are sure to help you.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/.

Comment: cplusplus.com is a horrible reference, please use something else (such as en.cppreference.com).

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  I tried looking at the site you mention and it made my eyes hurt; the layout and font selections are awful.  Besides, a reference is only truly awful if it contains incorrect information.  In all my time using cplusplus.com, I've never found it to be incorrect.  Lacking perhaps at times, but not incorrect.

Comment: @H2CO3 Your personal opinion

Comment: @paranaix Yes, although an opinion that is very widely held amongst experienced programmers. cplusplus is known to contain many errors compared to cppreference. There was even a huge post about how to deal with C++ beginners being introduced to cplusplus (and thus teaching them bad habits), but it's been removed for being off-topic. I use cplusplus for quickly looking up syntax (and only because of the convenience of it usually being the first hit on google), but when I want more assurance of accuracy I always use cppreference.

Comment: @JBentley - It's really that rife with errors?  I've never found it to be so erroneous, but perhaps I've just not been looking at the error-laden parts.  If you have citations available to support your claims, I'd love to see them (seriously, not snark).  (I guess I could JFGI, but you made the claim...)

Comment: @Lotharyx Yes. There was a good Stackoverflow post discussing it, but it's been deleted. [This blog post](http://kera.name/articles/2013/02/cplusplus-com-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/) (which is written by [a 99k rep Stackoverflow user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) who is active in the C++ tag) summarizes it.

Comment: @JBently Thanks for the link.  I guess I had never noticed because I never turn to cplusplus.com for coding examples, only API documentation.  Good to know, though; I'll think twice before directing people there in the future.

Comment: @Lotharyx It contains all sorts of incorrect and misleading information. And gfx doesn't really matter if we're talking about a reference (granted, it could be better, but as long as cppreference is correct and cplusplus.com is wrong, I just don't care.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the standard C++ containers such as vector.

```
#include <vector>

class Product{
};

class Book : public Product{
};

class Magazine : public Product{
};

class MusicCD : public Product{
};


int main(){

    std::vector<Product *> pro;

    pro.push_back(new Book);
    pro.push_back(new Magazine);
    pro.push_back(new MusicCD);


}
```

Comment: Yes, although Mgetz' answer is superior as it takes care of memory ownership / management.

Comment: its giving error no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Comment: @user3183539 what compiler are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 express

Comment: @user3183539 then you'll need to do it the C++03TR1 way.

Comment: what is the C++03TR1 way ?

Comment: its not working in my program but when i just c/p ur post and try to build there is no error . but my program is the same shit :S why is it not working

Comment: I'm guessing its not working because something is off with one of your constructors.  Can you post the code that contains  your objects?